# Looking for a free dvd burning program which has basic video editing to make a menu?

Tags: software, software-recommendation, producing

I just shot some video in 720 using my kodak playsport zx5. I know HD videos don't fit on DVD and i'll have to compress / edit them. I don't want to buy any advanced programs right now since i'm just starting with video editing. I'm familiar with imgburn and other dvd burning apps but I am looking for a program that will let me do basic video editing and the ability to create a basic dvd menu.

Would like the app to run on XP and or Vista

Thanks

Comment: You'll be more likely to get answers if you include what OS you're running, willing to run, budget, etc...

Comment: @Josh I did mention Free. Updating my question now to include OS

Comment: What do you mean by "editing"? Making animated menus or editing videos before exporting them for a dvd? The title of the question confused me a bit.

Comment: @InanBerbatov Making menu's no animation just a simple menu to play either part 1 or part 2. Kind of like chapter menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/) is a cross platform, free DVD authoring tool. It probably has all the features you want, and works pretty good. Usage is really easy as seen on their [guide](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/documents?id=70).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Movie Maker and Windows DVD Maker. Both are free and already installed on your PC if you have Vista (go to Start > All Programs - i don't remember)

Comment: Yep - this is what I use. Have played with various other ones, but this is simple, convenient and actually very good at doing even animated menus.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will find one that can do all that for free, but...you could download a trial of Adobe Premiere and Encore, they have a free 30-day limitless trial...

While it is not one software to do all of that, Premiere is pretty simple to learn and so is Encore and they work very well with eachother.